# Are Spring Integration Extensions up-to-date and useable?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-integration

Does anyone know what the state is of the Spring Integration Extensions at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions ?

Some seem outdated with regards to Spring versions. And others, whilst updated, don't seem to have recent releases or snapshots available at http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/integration/ .

For example I wanted to integrate with AWS, but cant find a release or snapshot for the latest version of Spring Integration. And SQS support has been "coming soon" for some time.

The outdatedness of those that do exist, and lack of clarity on what is intended, make me concerned to use any of them. Does anyone know what the Spring team's intention is with regards to the release cycle of these extensions? Are they viewed as incubators that will eventually move into Spring Integration core, or something else?

Cheers,
Menno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Integration extensions are community provided, and they will constantly change according to the will of the community. Your best chance is to get in touch with the contributors of the AWS extension.

You should use them, once you understand what they are doing, there are no more guarantees than other Spring projects, only the fact that others are also using it.

Comment: The main contributor to the AWS extension has been busy on other things; he has said he'll get back to it at some point. These projects are generally community lead; we generally release versions when someone has provided updates. Snapshots are built automatically after a commit it merged; milestones and releases are done when requested. Anyone can contribute (just sign the CLA per the main [contributing.md](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)). They generally will remain as extensions unless the community wants them pulled into the main project.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail Gary. It may be worth adding this info to the Integration Extensions Github page, as it just states that the extensions are part of the SpringSource organization.